# Need help about a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new at Javascript and jQuery. I need help with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#createDiv').click(function (){
            $("<div/>").html("<span id='myInstance2' style='display: block;'>New Folder</span>").css("display", "none").appendTo("#results").fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have this function to click and create a new `<span>` tag with a text. You can see I have an ID `myInstance2`. So what I am trying to do is when I click and the span is created, I would like to make this span live-editable. Like I can rename this "New folder" into whatever I want.

If anyone can help it would be great. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: How does what it does now differ from what you want it to do?

Comment: `style='display: block;'>New Folder</span>").css("display", "none")` You're seriously defeating you're own purpose here

Comment: Add the `contenteditable` attribute to the span. That will do the trick

Comment: ... and don't use `id='myInstance2'` but rather use `class='myInstance2'`

Comment: Normally a span is NOT editable, that is what and input tag is for.  IF you want it editable, you would need to add some library that supports that functionality.  Please clarify your full intended use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I catch what I think you're trying to do, it's not quite feasable the way you imagine. However, there are tricks. The following is one of them. The idea is to insert a "hidden" input where the span is, then create functions to show the input and hide span when needed (like when user clicks on span. Something like so:

## jsFiddle

### HTML

```
<button id="createDiv">Start</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#createDiv, #results span { cursor: pointer; }
#results div {
    background: #FFA;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em 1em 2em;
}
#results input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
//  Call for document .onload event
$(function() {
    //  Normal Click event asignement, same as $("#createDiv").click(function
    $("#createDiv").on("click", function(e) {
        //  Simply creating the elements one by one to remove confusion
        var newDiv = $("<div />", { class: "new-folder" }),  //  Notice, each child variable is appended to parent
            newInp = $("<input />", { type: "text", value: "New Folder", class: "title-inp" }).appendTo(newDiv),
            newSpan = $("<span />", { id: "myInstance2", text: "New Folder", class: "title-span" }).appendTo(newDiv);
        //  Everything created and seated, let's append this new div to it's parent
        $("#results").append(newDiv);
    });

    //  the following use the ".delegate" side of .on
    //  This means that ALL future created elements with the same classname, 
    //    inside the same parent will have this same event function added
    $("#results").on("click", ".new-folder .title-span", function(e) {
        //  This hides our span as it was clicked on and shows our trick input, 
        //    also places focus on input
        $(this).hide().prev().show().focus();
    });
    $("#results").on("blur", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
        //  tells the browser, when user clicks away from input, hide input and show span
        //    also replaces text in span with new text in input
        $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
    });
    //  The following sures we get the same functionality from blur on Enter key being pressed
    $("#results").on("keyup", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
        //  Here we grab the key code for the "Enter" key
        var eKey = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (eKey == 13) { // if enter key was pressed then hide input, show span, replace text
            $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Perfect and Exact What I need . Millions of Thanks

Comment: The Example you gave me was super . I was thinking to add something extra with that . Like if rename is done and same name comes for two  times can it make to give a warning and give a chance o rename again . Warning like "The name you gave already have please chose different name"

Please that will be perfect for my project . Thanks in advance 

All the best

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is put a delegated event handler on the enclosing, static element where span will reside `#results`.  The handler will hide the `span` and reveal an `input`.  I don't know your code well enough but you likely want the id on the `input` instead of the span. You did not say you wanted to go from editable back to "read-only" so I did not do that.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/p8VwB/)**

```
    $('#createDiv').on('click', function () {
        var str = "Click here to edit it";  // New Folder
        $("<div/>").html("<span id='myInstance2' class='editToggler' style='display: block;'>" + str + "</span><input class='editToggler' style='display: none' value='" + str + "'/>").appendTo("#results").fadeIn();
        $(this).off('click');
    });



    $('#results').on('click', 'span', function () {
        $('.editToggler').toggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work and is much simpler than other answers (imo):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){
      $('#createDiv').click(function (){
        $("<div />").html("<span onclick='$(this).html(prompt(\"Rename \"+$(this).html()))' id='myInstance2' style='display: block; cursor:pointer;'>New Folder</span>").css("display", "none").appendTo("#results").fadeIn();
      });
  });
</script>
```

When you click your `span`, you will be prompted for its new name. To visual represent that your created the `span` is clickable, I also added `cursor:pointer` to the style for the `span`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XJ6Cn/

Edit: P.S: Do you create more than one `span`using this method? If so, you should create the `id`s dynamically, because `id`s are meant to be unique. If you want a string to be the same for all `span`s, you can set it as a `class` instead.

Comment: Thank you SOOOO much it's kind of  what I was looking :)

Comment: Also is there a way if  it can  rename without creating a pop up window ?

thanks

Comment: I used a pop-up in my example because I don't know how exactly you want to edit it. If you want to use an input element you can use the code SpYk3HH posted in his answer.

Comment: in my opinion this is awful.  inline callback creates a code maintenance nightmare. also `prompt` is something you want to avoid because of it's behaviour of locking navigation including switching to another tab and requirement to interact with it.