# Click a button to open a input field with Blinking Cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Code that I got form my first post :[Need help about a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401965/need-help-about-a-function)

I modified this code and trying to work like how I want .But I got Stuck in one point .

JSfiddle LINK : http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/qzKWD/

Here is the Code :

**HTML**

```
<button id="createDiv">Start</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #createDiv, #results span { cursor: pointer; }
#results div {
    background: #FFA;
    border: 1px solid;
   width:auto;
}
#results input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
    //  Call for document .onload event
$(function() {
    //  Normal Click event asignement, same as $("#createDiv").click(function
    $("#createDiv").on("click", function(e) {
        //  Simply creating the elements one by one to remove confusion
        var newDiv = $("<div />", { class: "new-folder" }),  //  Notice, each child variable is appended to parent
            newInp = $("<input />", { name: "inpTitle[]",style:"display:block ;border:solid 1px #fa9a34", type: "text", value: "Unnamed Group", class: "title-inp" }).appendTo(newDiv),
            newSpan = $("<span />", { id: "myInstance2",style:"display:none", text: "Unnamed Group", class: "title-span" }).appendTo(newDiv);
        //  Everything created and seated, let's append this new div to it's parent
        $("#results").append(newDiv);
    });

    //  the following use the ".delegate" side of .on
    //  This means that ALL future created elements with the same classname, 
    //    inside the same parent will have this same event function added
    $("#results").on("click", ".new-folder .title-span", function(e) {
        //  This hides our span as it was clicked on and shows our trick input, 
        //    also places focus on input
        $(this).hide().prev().show().focus();
    });
    $("#results").on("blur", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
        //  tells the browser, when user clicks away from input, hide input and show span
        //    also replaces text in span with new text in input
        $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
    });
    //  The following sures we get the same functionality from blur on Enter key being pressed
    $("#results").on("keyup", ".new-folder .title-inp", function(e) {
        //  Here we grab the key code for the "Enter" key
        var eKey = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (eKey == 13) { // if enter key was pressed then hide input, show span, replace text
            $(this).hide().next().text($(this).val()).show();
        }
    });
})
```

WHAT it does now is , when I click the Start Button Create a input Box which Can be Rename and can save as text . BUT what I am wanting is .. WHEN I  click the Start button it will Create input With BLINKING cursor which is not here now . Now it become active when I clicked on it . But I am wanting it should Start blinking When it's Created . Is possible with any jquery or java scripts ?

Comment: Another improvement would be to use `placeholder` instead of `value` for input (text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) event.

```
$("#results").append(newDiv);
newInp.focus();
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is the Simplest  Way :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `newInp.focus()` to give the textbox focus, but you presumably also want the cursor at the end?

Use the following to achieve that:

```
$.fn.setCursorToTextEnd = function() {
    $initialVal = this.val();
    this.val('');
    this.val($initialVal);
};
```

Then do:

`newInp.focus().setCursorToTextEnd();`

Credit should go to [Gavin G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227297/gavin-g) for the [`setCursorToTextEnd()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609405/set-focus-after-last-character-in-text-box#answer-9406052)

I've applied this to your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/qzKWD/3/

Comment: problem with this is if added a couple of boxes and you delete the text of the box that is in between two boxes the box with deleted items shrinks a line size

Answer (score 1):

You need the [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) event.

A solution would be finding the input inside of `newDiv` element that is appended to `#results`, and then focusing on it.

```
// Inside of click handler
$("#results").append(newDiv);
newDiv.find("input").focus();
```

Another solution is to focus directly on `newInp` element that is same `<input>`.

```
// Inside of click handler
$("#results").append(newDiv);
newInp.focus();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qzKWD/1/)

Comment: 2nd one is Better One and I liked this one . Thank you Very much

Comment: Yes, and it's more efficient.